# When is the vue element style properties determined?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I tried to access an element style properties on mounted through $refs, but it turns out they are all empty string. So when are these properties determined?

```js
<template>
  <div ref="title"><h1>This is title</h1></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted: function() {
    console.log("App mounted");
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      console.log(this.$el.style);
    });
  },
}
</script>
```

Console output is

```js
{
accentColor: ""
additiveSymbols: ""
alignContent: ""
alignItems: ""
alignSelf: ""
alignmentBaseline: ""
all: ""
animation: ""
animationDelay: ""
animationDirection: ""
...
}
```

Comment: Your element has no `style` attribute so it shouldn't be a surprise that all style properties are empty